# DropzoneJS thumbnailWidth and thumbHeight don't work

Tags: dropzone.js

### Problem

I'm using dropzone to handle multiple image uploads. I want it to generate 280x280px thumbnails. Despite my best efforts, it keeps generating 100x100px thumbnails.

### Code

Here is my code:

```
   Dropzone.options.addPhotosForm = {
     createImageThumbnails: true,
     thumbnailWidth: "280",
     thumbnailHeight: "280",
     ...
   }
```

Here is my contact form:

```
      <form action="{{ route('store_photo_path', [$rooms->slug]) }}" 
          method="POST" class="dropzone" id="addPhotosForm">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      </form>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image {
      width: 280px;
      height: 280px;
    }
```

I have tried with and without the quotes, with single and with double quotes. Nothing has worked so far.

Do you guys know what could be the problem?

Thanks!

I have read and tried these solutions:
[quotes/no quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323836/how-do-i-get-better-quality-thumbnails-with-dropzone-js),
[xhrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081416/dropzone-js-resize-image-to-fit-the-thumbnail-size),
[any of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740117/dropzone-resize-function), and
[jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811498/jquery-dropzone-js-change-thumbnail-width-to-100/33813643#33813643).

### Solution:

I finally realized what I was doing wrong. I create the thumbnails in my Photo.php file. Under the makeThumbail function, I had "->fit(100)" which forced the thumbnail to be a 100x100 image. After changing this to "->fit(280)", this fixed the problem.

Here is my code:

#### Code for solution

```
public function makeThumbnail()
{
    Image::make($this->path)
        ->fit(280)
        ->save($this->thumbnail_path);
}
```

Comment: Your form's id is "addPhotosForm" ?

Comment: Exactly.  id="addPhotosForm"

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue, I used your code spinets and got this result: https://dry-everglades-43790.herokuapp.com/ which seems working fine. it could be something else in your code.

Comment: Thanks @RabahG and Romias for helping. I noticed the problem was actually within the Photo.php file, where the thumbnails were created. Unfortunately, I completely forgot about this file when debugging. I went through the code again to try to figure out how the thumbnails were actually created and it brought me back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

I finally realized what I was doing wrong. I create the thumbnails in my Photo.php file. Under the makeThumbail function, I had "->fit(100)" which forced the thumbnail to be a 100x100 image. After changing this to "->fit(280)", this fixed the problem.

#### Here is my code:

```
public function makeThumbnail()
{
    Image::make($this->path)
        ->fit(280)
        ->save($this->thumbnail_path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides modifying the size of the thumbnail as you are doing, you need to modify the `.dz-image` class in the CSS file accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Romias, I forgot to list that in the post. You can now see my CSS. Unfortunately, that hasn't helped, at least with the code that I currently have. Any idea why?

Comment: I have followed this question completely with no results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031705/dropzone-thumbnail-width-image-size